# 'PlusClass' is obsolete

Tags: xamarin.android, google-plus, google-api-client

When initializing GoogleApiClient, I get this warning:

> 'PlusClass' is obsolete: 'This class is obsoleted in this android
>   platform'

What are its alternative?

Code:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
   .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
   .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
   .AddApi(PlusClass.API)
   .AddScope(new Scope(Scopes.Profile))
   .Build();
```

Version:

```
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Plus" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and after a lot of digging around and reverse engineering java examples I arrived at the code below.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
        .RequestProfile()
        .Build();

    _GoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .AddApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .Build();
}
```

Packages

```
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth.Base" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Plus" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
```